# Term for shifting work to idle machines

Tags: terminology, distributed-systems, computer-networks

I am looking for a term here. A while ago, i was told about a network in which all the computers are connected in parallel, and when a computer is idle, the central server sends heavy cpu usage tasks to that idle computer.

This is often used in pharmaceutical companies working on protein structure configurations, or as the CS community more commonly knows, the bit mining community.

Any who, i know this is often called grid computing, however there was another name for it. Scapegoating? or something like that. Not quite sure. The term has really been bugging me. Can you guys help me out?

Comment: There is *work stealing*, but that works the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called **[volunteer computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volunteer_computing)**.